# Add Event Listener on Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and can't figure out why the following code isn't working:

```js
var toChange = document.getElementById("greeting");
toChange.addEventListener("mouseOver", function() {
  this.innerHTML = "Hi";
  });
```

```html
  <p id="greeting">Hello.</p>
```

I've thoroughly researched event listeners, and I can't figure out why this code won't work. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Event names are case-sensitive.  Here's your code, with `mouseOver` replaced with `mouseover`.

```js
var toChange = document.getElementById("greeting");
toChange.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  this.innerHTML = "Hi";
  });
```

```html
  <p id="greeting">Hello.</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `"mouseover"` in lowercase instead.